# Let users register weight each day and save it in DB

Tags: php, database, users, mysql, user-meta

I need a way that lets my users register they're weight (kg) and maybe % of bodyfat and save that information on each user in the DB.

Then i need a way to output that number again on the logged in user

What would be the easiest approach to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel the best way to do is add two options `Body weight` and `Body fat(%)` in the user profile, and then you can show it with the user logged from the db. I guess this would be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

If that's only about storing the current value, then check out [update_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta) and [get user meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta). But if you want to keep track of older entries, then I think creating new post type ([register_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)) with author_id of the user would be the way to go (each new weight record will be the new post)

Comment: thanks for the great tips, but to save each number as a post is not an option in this case

Comment: Why? You can of course create your own table with these records (user_id, weight, bodyfat, timestamp) and write handlers to write and read these data, but wp_posts functions are very generic and handle these for you.